# pass identify number car to input field php

Tags: php, mysql, input, field

I have a query for personal identity code, it works, and I have put a button to enter a new record for that personal identification code, but the input does not work and it records the information but not the personal identification

i need to pass personal code in php pages and save to mysql

Comment: Can you please show some code and clarify your question more?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague without some code, but I gather you want something like this:

**index.html**

```html
<!--- use POST instead of GET, to keep "personal identity code" out of the URL  --->
<form action="addRecord.php" method="post"> 

<label for="code">Personal Identity Code: </label>
<input type="text" id="code" name="code" placeholder="1234">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

**addRecord.php**

```php
$code = $_POST["code"];

// your sql query here...
```

Make sure you appropriately sanitize you input, before running an sql query on it.